# How can I get data of the current week in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

How can I get data of the current week in Oracle? Assume that the week goes from Sunday to Saturday

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE DATEFIELD IS {WITHIN CURRENT WEEK THAT GOES FROM 12AM ON SUNDAY TO 11:59PM ON SATURDAY}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Oracle trunc(sysdate,'IW') returns the first day of the week and add 6 to get the end of week.

```
-- not tested
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE DATEFIELD >= trunc ( sysdate, 'iw' )
AND  DATEFIELD  < trunc ( sysdate, 'iw' ) + 5
```

Comment: Not quite, because the OP explicitly stated the week is from Sunday to Saturday, and the ISO week (IW) runs from Monday to Sunday. This can be fixed easily; do you know how?

Comment: It can be done by subtracting -1 from trunc ( sysdate, 'iw' ).

Comment: That's half of it. It will not work for a Sunday (assuming someone might run the query on a Sunday for some reason). The full solution (that works without exceptions) is to add 1 to sysdate, then truncate to 'iw', and *then* subtract 1 from the result. You may want to edit your answer, to show the correct formula for the OP's problem. (Also: since "data" may exist on weekends, in the very last condition you should add 7 rather than 5 - just in case. If "data" is sales, for example, they may occur on Saturdays or Sundays too.)

Comment: Use `DY` *(starting day of the week)* instead of `IW` *(first day of ISO calendar week)*.

Comment: @Andreas - first, `DY` simply means short name of the day-of-the-week (such as SUN for Sunday), it has nothing to do with "start of week". Second, "starting day of week" is locale dependent; the OP requested a query with hard-coded week, not locale dependent. The solution shown here (after the corrections discussed in the comments above) is the right approach for what the OP requested.

Comment: @mathguy In `TO_CHAR`, the `DY` format means *"abbreviated name of day"* [¹](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A), but in `TRUNC`/`ROUND`, the `DY` format means *"starting day of the week"* [²](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8), according to the *Oracle Documentation**.

Comment: I tested @hkandpal query against my data, and it worked, but I will need to test with more scenarios to confirm

Comment: @Andreas yes, but bear in mind *The starting day of the week used by the format models DAY, DY, and D is specified implicitly by the initialization parameter `NLS_TERRITORY`.* The `NLS_TERRITORY` might be different in every session.